# Re-grouping of Gantt chart Y axis for second time breaks

Tags: angular, highcharts

The purpose for me to have a live data visualization using gantt chart.
Which means the chart will be updated like every 10 seconds , this works fine if the gantt chart Y series structure doesn't change , if the series structure changes it breaks let me give you an example

If I have 3 categories grouped for the first time it works , after lets say 10 seconds I am re grouping the series taking elements from 2nd category and assigning that to first category series it breaks Below is the working example .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ucqgp

PS : If in above link project gives an error , please update anything in app.component.html and save it automatically rectifies (Guess issue with Stack-blitz) .

Let me know if am doing something wrong

Comment: This issue is a bug. Check this PR with fixes about updating point: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/pull/11642. You can report an issue on HIghcharts github here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: @WojciechChmiel thank you for that , But i see that the PR is related to breaking individual point , i couldn't get much info/fixes . Could you please help on this

Comment: This issue is reported as a bug here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11739. Please follow this thread.